# Android RingtoneManager wont work in API 23 and above.

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have been trying to get the system's default notification sound to play using RingtoneManager. The code works fine until API 22 but just stops working beyond that.

This is how I am doing it,

```
Uri notificationTone = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notificationTone);
                    r.play();
```

What am I missing ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's permission issue in >22, you need to request permission at runtime,

[you can checked here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I understand that APIs beyond 22 require runtime permissions for certain features but in this case it doesn't seem like a permission related issue. What permission would fix it ?

Comment: Returns a valid ringtone URI. No guarantees on which it returns. If it cannot find one, returns null. If it can only find one on external storage and the caller doesn't have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, returns null.